# ArcGIS 10 PDF exports: toggle polygon layer visibility?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, layers, export, pdf

In the past I have been able to export my .mxd to PDF and I have been able to turn individual point layer's visibilty on/off within the layer tab (if the layers are in a groub in the .mxd's table of contents). See the below screen shot, where all layers under 'Act booked' can be toggled.
[image]

When I try this with polygon layers, the option to turn on/off visibilty of these layers within the PDF is not there.

As far as I can see I have used the same export options for both .mxds; 'Export PDF Layers Only' is selected for both.

Is it simply not possible to export polygon layers individualy or am I missing something here?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.0, SP5 on windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that [Knowledge Base Technical Article 30882](http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/30882) (which says that it also applies to ArcGIS 10) may offer you an explanation:

> Problem:  Layers in a PDF exported from ArcGIS Desktop do not match
>   the layers of the map
>
> As of ArcGIS 9.2, exported PDF files contain layer information, so
>   certain layers can be enabled and disabled in a compatible PDF reader.
>   The layers in the PDF may not exactly match the layers in the source
>   map document. This document addresses the reasons this might occur at
>   ArcGIS 9.2.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out the transparency of the polygon layers were causing them to be rasterized during the export process, thus 'merging' all the layers into one.